# label position based on neighbor label c#

Tags: c#, position, label

Supposing that I have two labels with variable text. Label 1 is in the center of the screen. I can position Label 2 on the right side of Label 1:

```
label1.Location = (WIDTH / 2, Height / 2)
label2.Location = new Point(label1.Right, label1.Top);
```

Form output:

```
 _______________ 
|               |
|      100 200  |
|_______________|
```

Now I want do the same, but position Label 2 on the left side of Label 1. How can I do this?

Form output:

```
 _______________ 
|               |  
|  200 100      |
|_______________|
```

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Then you can simply set the anchors in the GUI-Editor.

Comment: Either this is a too easy question (there are already 2 good answers) or a *complicated* one. I'd recommend using [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) for the purpose of layouting controls, because it's a step in wpf direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `label2` is already sized correctly, you can just subtract its width from the left side of `label1`:

```
label2.Location = new Point(label1.Left - label2.Width, label1.Top)
```

Diagram:

```
  -----(label1.Left - label2.Width)
  |
  |   -----label1.Left
 _|___|_________ 
| v   v        |  
| +---+---+ <--------label1.Top
| |200|100|    |
| +---+---+    |  
| '---'        |
|___|__________|
    |
    -----label2.Width
```

Answer (score 0):

Position the second label starting from the left point of the first label and subtracting the witdh of the one to be placed

```
label2.Location = new Point(label1.Left - label2.Width, label1.Top);
```

By the way, the value used for your first label should consider the width and height of the label to be really at the center of the label container. 
So assuming you want the first label at the center of its containing form you should use a formula like this

```
int leftPos = (this.Width / 2) - (label1.Width / 2);
int topPos = (this.Height / 2) - (label1.height / 2);
label1.Location = new Point(leftPos, topPos)
```